# How can i add a value/entry to a field within a collection in firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

[Firebase DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiFYD.png)

[My code trying to addtodo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQqEz.png)
[error on console once i click add to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZHt6.png)

Just wondering does anyone know how i would go about getting my addtodo to store in my todolist field in the house subcollection
 `

```
todo_title:string;
  todo_description: string;
  todo_last_date: Date;
  todo_owner: string;

  constructor(private navCtrl: NavController, private toastCtrl:ToastController) { 
  this.todo_owner = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
  }
  ngOnInit() {

    firebase.firestore().collection("house").doc("this.house.id").collection("toDoList").add({
      title: this.todo_title,
      description: this.todo_description,
      last_date: this.todo_last_date,
      owner: this.todo_owner,
      created: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp
      ()
    }).then((docRef) => {
      this.toastCtrl.create({
        message: "toDo has been added!",
        duration: 2000
      }).then((toast) => {
        toast.present();
        this.navCtrl.navigateBack
      })
       }).catch((err) => {
         this.toastCtrl.create({
           message: "ToDo has been Added",
           duration: 3000
         }).then((toast) => {
           toast.present();
         })
         })
       }

  }`
```

Answer (score 1):

The error tells you that the value you pass to `title` (the property of the object you pass to the `add()` method) is undefined. So, in other words, `this.todo_title` seems to be `undefined`.

---

In addition, I think that you should do:

```
firebase.firestore().collection("house").doc(this.house.id).collection("toDoList").add(...)
```

Note `doc(this.house.id)` instead of `doc("this.house.id")`: with the latter you pass a string with a value of `"this.house.id"`.

Comment: Property 'house' does not exist on type 'AddTodoPage' when i change it to that i get this error on vs code.

Comment: @Keaner111 You have to debug your code and verify that the values you are using are the correct ones. It seems that, in our code, `this` is not what you expect.